# I need help reducing query time of complex select CASE expression (with subqueries)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to make a query run faster. The query is huge but I think the main focus should be on the complex select CASE query part.

```
        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT
                g2.montant_ht_actualise_echeance 
            FROM
                base_gid g2 
            WHERE
                g.num_contrat = g2.num_contrat 
                AND g.code_nidt = g2.code_nidt 
                AND g.libelle_rubrique_echeance = g2.libelle_rubrique_echeance 
                AND g.nom_tiers = g2.nom_tiers 
                AND (
                    g.year_echeance - g2.year_echeance
                ) = 1 LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance 
            WHEN g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance > ((SELECT
                g4.montant_ht_actualise_echeance 
            FROM
                base_gid g4 
            WHERE
                g.num_contrat = g4.num_contrat 
                AND g.code_nidt = g4.code_nidt 
                AND g.libelle_rubrique_echeance = g4.libelle_rubrique_echeance 
                AND g.nom_tiers = g4.nom_tiers 
                AND (
                    g.year_echeance - g4.year_echeance
                ) = 1 LIMIT 1) * 1.1) THEN g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance 
            WHEN g.code_indice LIKE 'ICC%' 
            OR g.code_indice = '' THEN CASE 
                WHEN g.periode_courante_indice_echeance IN (SELECT
                    indice_icc.icc_periode 
                FROM
                    indice_icc) THEN ROUND(g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance,
                2) 
                ELSE ROUND((g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance * :filtre_indice_icc),
                2) 
            END 
            ELSE g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance 
        END) montant_ht_actualise_echeance
```

The logic of the case statement is the following :

I am trying to edit the 'montant_actualise_echeance' column

- CASE 1 : No bill previous year -> no change to 'montant_actualise_echeance'
- CASE 2 : The previous year bill * 1.1 is lower or equal to montant_actualise_echeance  -> no change to 'montant_actualise_echeance'
- CASE 3 : If icc column is like ICC... or is empty :

  - If icc table has the timestamp of the current row -> no change to 'montant_actualise_echeance'
  - Else -> montant_ht_actualise_echeance * icc (user input)
- ELSE -> no change to 'montant_actualise_echeance'

Here is the result of EXPLAIN :
[image: EXPLAIN query result]

I am using MariaDB 10.1

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  No one should (or likely will) parse that 100+ line query to understand your problem.  You need to give us a _minimal_ question.

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: It's not the `CASE` but the subquery.

Comment: Hello @TimBiegeleisen . Actually I was hoping just to focus on the case expression so I will remove the rest of the query

Comment: You are also using `GROUP BY` incorrectly, since you group by only a few columns, yet select many other columns.

Comment: I will look into that thanks @TimBiegeleisen . I hope the post is more clear now. I was wondering if it was possible to convert those subqueries into left joins.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making sure your subquery can use a "convering index". The index I woudl make sure exists should be something like:

```
create index ix1 on base_gid (
  num_contrat, code_nidt, libelle_rubrique_echeance,
  nom_tiers, year_echeance, montant_ht_actualise_echeance
);
```

The other useful index (if you don't already have it) is:

```
create index ix2 on indice_icc (icc_periode);
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply, but I already have those index. I was wondering if it was possible to convert those subqueries into left joins